# Behaviour of rownum in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by, rownum

I observed a strange behaviour with ROWNUM in Oracle with static tables. I am trying pagination with query like below

```
select * from (
     select the_data,rownum as seqn from the_table  
  )  where seqn <= somenumber and seqn >= othernumber
```

However when I execute query multiple times I observe that the rownum value returned is not unique for a row ie if a row appears at rownum 25 for the first time it appears at rownum 125 for second execution

This issue does not appear if I do a order by like,

```
select * from (
     select the_data,rownum as seqn from the_table order by column3 
  )  where seqn <= somenumber and seqn >= othernumber
```

However order by decreases performance. Is this normal or is there any other way to improve performance.

Comment: This is a FAQ. You will get your answer in the question I marked as duplicate. In your first query, there is no **ORDER BY** in the subquery, hence there is no **guarantee** of the order of the rows fetched.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B But for static table should rownum not be same everytime you fire query

Comment: **NO**, never. `ROWNUM` is a pseudo column which is assigned to a row after it passes the predicate phase. Rows are not stored in any order, neither they are fetched in any order. To ensure the order, you MUST always specify **ORDER BY**.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B But order by decreases performance. Is there any other way to do this without using order by

Comment: There is always an overhead with an explicit sort. On 12c you could use the new **Top-n** ow limiting feature, however, the additional cost to sort the rows will always be there.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B Another problem with sort by is I get a table space error when the number of records is in billions

Comment: You need to look at the `sort_area_size`.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B, will it be possible to create a column in  select clause on par with ROWNUM which will always have unique value for row in output result set

Answer (score -1):

You should check oracle documents for this question. Followed links may be helpful for you http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm#SQLRF06100

```
One example: 
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS R, T.* FROM T ) AS TR WHERE R <= 10;
```

**T is a table name. R is a row**

Comment: To limit the number of rows returned from a query to the 10 first rows of table T, use the following query:
`SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS R, 
     T.* 
   FROM T
) AS TR 
   WHERE R <= 10;`

**T is a table name.
R is a row**

Comment: @Khamill but will this remain constant when query is executed multiple times and no order by is required in query